# Why doesn't latex style knitr::kable show up in Rstudio?

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to preview my table in a .Rmd in RStudio and would like to use the latex style but the output is a blank box whenever I set the style as "latex". It appears in the pdf once knit.

[blank box shown where table should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPih0.png)

```
form_o3 <- tibble(
  Quartile = c("0 (Min)",".25", ".5 (Median)", ".75", "1 (Max)","IQR"),
  Value = c(o3_quart[1],o3_quart[2],o3_quart[3],o3_quart[4],o3_quart[5],IQR(o3_raw$ozone_ppm)))

kable(form_o3,"latex",col.names = c('Quartile','Value'))
```

Other styles such as "simple" work but I can't make the latex one display. I have texworks installed on my computer for creating the knitted pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

By the belo sample you can change the style, but it will work as expected when you knit the document to create the PDF:

```
form_o3 <- tibble(
  Quartile = c("0 (Min)",".25", ".5 (Median)", ".75", "1 (Max)","IQR"),
  Value = c(o3_quart[1],o3_quart[2],o3_quart[3],o3_quart[4],o3_quart[5],IQR(o3_raw$ozone_ppm)))

kable(form_o3, "simple", col.names = c('Quartile','Value'))
```